# Gif image is not showing its animation in android application

Tags: android, android-studio, universal-image-loader

In my android application, I am using universal image loader to show images from url. During loading of image I want a gif image to be shown. But the gif image added is not showing any animation.
Here is my code to display image.

```
private static final DisplayImageOptions.Builder DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS_BUIDLER = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
        .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300, true, false, false))
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_image)
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loadingx)
        .showImageOnFail(sampleapp.sample.com.sampleapp.R.drawable.default_image).cacheOnDisk(true)
        .cacheInMemory(true).bitmapConfig(Config.ARGB_8888);
```

what changes should I make to show an animated gif image during loading  time image

Comment: Go throught [with link to find solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30277940/8012913)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use glide for gif image loading...

```
Glide  
    .with( context )
    .load( gifUrl )
    .asGif()
    .error( R.drawable.full_cake )
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    .into( imageViewGif );
```

To understand follow the link - 
[here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos)

If you want to use ProgressBar then create a method like below -

```
public void loadImage(Context context, String url, ImageView img, final ProgressBar eProgressBar) {

        eProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        eProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        eProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .crossFade()
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
                .into(img);
    }
```

Use this method and pass your parameter value through it... :)

Comment: I want to use a gif image during loading time of image url. Is there any way to implement that

Comment: Yes, :) I edit my answer as you asked. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Image Loader doesnot Support Gif see [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/1254)   Try using other libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)  which supports gif

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.yourgif)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Does Universal Image Loader support default progressbar or spinner

Comment: whats the relation between progressbar and image loader ,i cant understand what you are asking

Comment: You said that universal image loader doesn't support gif. If so then I just need to show something moving during loading of image. There is default progress bar in android. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653816/show-indeterminate-progressbar-while-loading-image-with-universal-image-loader) show how to show progress bar during loading of image. I tried it,But it also causes some error.

Comment: you can use an image of loading as place holder ,  Placeholder image will be shown until the original image is loaded.

Comment: I used a gif image as place holder.But It does'nt show any animation.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer by using glide library. But  glide is slower than universal image loader.

```
Glide.with(getActivity().getApplication())
                .load(item.imageUrl)
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(getActivity().getApplication()).load(R.drawable.loadingx))
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.image);
```